# C-d and C-S-d key bindings in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I try to bind Ctrl+d and Ctrl+Shif+d like this

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-d") 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
```

I'm unable to bind Ctrl+Shift combination, the firs one "C-d" binds to both with and without shift. What I do wrong?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You said in another comment that "`C-h k [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[d]` tells me `C-d (translated from C-S-d) runs the command delete-char`" so Emacs *is* seeing the intended sequence (n.b. that may not be the case in a terminal, but clearly your Emacs instance does recognise the sequence). I can't replicate the problem. Try with `emacs -Q`

Comment: @phils I've read somewhere that emacs (in terminal at least) has actually problem with recognizing  Shift key, so I decided to not use this combination at all...

Answer (score 1):

You already have the correct syntax.  It is likely that `C-S-d` is bound in a major- or minor-mode keymap which is taking precedence over the global keymap.

Try `C-h k C-S-d` (or `M-x describe-key C-S-d`) to find out what it the conflicting command is and what keymap it is in.

Then you can unset that key binding by adding one of the following to that mode's [mode hook](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeHooks).

```
(local-unset-key (kbd "C-S-d"))
```

**OR:**

I like to use the [bind-key](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) package.  With it you would do something like the following:

```
(unbind-key "C-S-d" the-offending-mode-map)
```

Comment: I think emacs doesn't recognize 'shift' at all... I've made "C-M-d" and it works. I need use Alt instead of Shift, but it's good enough...